# Из-за чего появляется исключение?

Tags: java, json, url, get

Исключение указывает на эту строку  `StringuserJsonStroke=getJsonFromServer(String.format("%s/%d", urlPath), 0);`

Вот весь класс

```
public class JsonPlaceholderApi {

    private String urlPath;

    public JsonPlaceholderApi(String urlPath) {
        this.urlPath = urlPath;
    }
    public User getUser(JSONObject jsonObject) throws IOException, JSONException {



//        JSONObject userRoot = new JSONObject(jsonObject);
        JSONObject userAddress = jsonObject.getJSONObject("address");
        JSONObject userCompany = jsonObject.getJSONObject("company");
        JSONObject addressGeo = userAddress.getJSONObject("geo");

        int userId = jsonObject.getInt("id");
        String userName = jsonObject.getString("name");
        String userNameName = jsonObject.getString("username");
        String userEmail = jsonObject.getString("email");
        String userPhone = jsonObject.getString("phone");
        String userWebSite = jsonObject.getString("website");

        String addressStreet = userAddress.getString("street");
        String addressSuite = userAddress.getString("suite");
        String addressCity = userAddress.getString("city");
        String addressZipcode = userAddress.getString("zipcode");

        double geoLat = addressGeo.getDouble("lat");
        double getLon = addressGeo.getDouble("lng");

        String companyName = userCompany.getString("name");
        String companyCatchPhrase = userCompany.getString("catchPhrase");
        String companyBs = userCompany.getString("bs");

        Geo geo = new Geo(geoLat, getLon);
        Address address = new Address(addressStreet, addressSuite, addressCity, addressZipcode, geo);
        Company company = new Company(companyName, companyCatchPhrase, companyBs);

        return new User(userId, userName, userNameName, userEmail, address, userPhone, userWebSite, company);
    }

   public ArrayList<User> getUserList() throws IOException, JSONException {


       String userJsonStroke = getJsonFromServer(String.format("%s/%d", urlPath), 0);

       JSONArray array = new JSONArray(userJsonStroke);

       ArrayList<User> userArrayList = new ArrayList<>();


       for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++){
           JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);

           User newUser = getUser(obj);

           userArrayList.add(newUser);
       }


        return  userArrayList;
    }

    private String getJsonFromServer(String urlPath, int timeout) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlPath);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        connection.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        connection.connect();

        int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        switch (serverResponseCode) {
            case 200:
            case 201:
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String tmpLine;
                while ((tmpLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(tmpLine).append("\n");
                }
                br.close();
                return sb.toString();
            case 404:
                Log.d(JsonPlaceholderApi.class.getName(), "page not found!");
                break;
            case 400:
                Log.d(JsonPlaceholderApi.class.getName(), "Bad request!");
                break;
            case 500:
                Log.d(JsonPlaceholderApi.class.getName(), "Internal server error");
                break;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Сама строчка находится в методе, который парсит json'ы

UserTask class

```
 public class UserTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            JsonPlaceholderApi api = new JsonPlaceholderApi("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
            try {
    //            User user = api.getUser(1);
    //            User user2 = api.getUser(2);
    //            User user3 = api.getUser(3);
                Log.d("Success",(api.getUserList().toString()));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы не указали что за ошибка (а это важнее, чем показать код) и у вас очень старый код в вопросе (в смысле образец примерно 5-ти летней давности) из чего можно сделать вывод о том, что у вас `NetworkOnMainTreadException`. Коли так - надо не в главном потоке запрос в сеть делать.

Comment: java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException? У тебя в String.format("%s/%d", urlPath) нет второго аргумента (который %d)

Comment: @Алексей   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground(), в AsyncTaske просто создаю экземпляр этого класса, и пытаюсь вывести результат в log

Comment: @toofack, в приведённой вами информации об ошибке собственно информации о ней нет. Приведите полный лог ошибки в тексте вопроса.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб прикрепил log  к вопросу

Comment: @toofack, лог надо бы текстом, не картинкой - иначе поисковики не смогут проинжексировать корректно страницу, но да ладно) В общем `Алексей` прав - у вас в строке `StringuserJsonStroke=getJsonFromServer(String.format("%s/%d", urlPath), 0);` 2 аргумента объявлено, а вы один передаёте. После `urlPath` должно быть ещё какое-то число. Или его вообще не должно быть в строке, т.е. `%d` надо удалить. Точнее не сказать - из кода не ясно что за строку вы получить хотите

Comment: @ЮрийСПб благодарю